# for_each() in C++

Tags: c++, foreach, compiler-errors

I've compiled my code on two different machines, which I thought had identical setups. However, one compiles without issues, and the other gives the following error.

```
LogEventReader.cpp(320) : error C3861: 'for_each': identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup
```

The relevant code:

```
#include <algorithm> 
...
for_each(messages.begin(), messages.end(), processXMLMessage);
```

Any ideas what the issue could be? TIA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A likely issue is that the first compiler wants a `using namespace std;` before allowing the use of undecorated identifiers from that namespace (such as `for_each`), while the second one is over-permissive and doesn't demand it.

Of course, as other answers and comments hotly pointed out, there are probably-preferable alternatives, such as explicitly spelling it `std::for_each` at each occurrence, or employing a *using **declaration*** (`using std::for_each;`) instead of the broader *using **directive*** (`using namespace std;`) -- but this (good) advice is not a response to your question of why one compiler would diagnose an error while another did not;-).

Comment: Yup, I just realized that and it fixed the issue.

Comment: using namespace std! Come on!

Comment: using namespace std is evil - who knows when you'll get a name collision?

Comment: Why wouldn't ADL work here, unless the iterator for 'messages' isn't in the std namespace?

Answer (score 13):

try `std::for_each()` instead. Perhaps it can't see the namespace.